# Can't see mesh when changing from Bump only to Displacement and bump

Tags: displacement

I tried to change from Bump only to but i couldn't see my mesh in rendered view mode.

[image]

Comment: great image....

Comment: Please add also an image showing your model as well as one showing all the displacement nodes. As a start, try to set the scale of the displacement node to 0 as otherwise it might displace your model completely out of the view.